# C# Analyzers: How to enforce XML doc on interface members (and not everything else)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn-code-analysis

I would like to enforce the usage of XML documentation on interface members in C# projects.

I'm looking for the same kind of behavior as [SA1600](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1600.md) or  [CS1591](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1591) but **limited to interfaces instead of all types**.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: _"How can I achieve this?"_ - you can't, sorry: StyleCop rules are not customizable, and CS1591 is also a rather blunt instrument. You'll have to somehow do it yourself, I recommend writing a simple program or Linqpad sketch that iterates over every `public interface` type in the built assembly (`.dll` file) and then compares that to what it reads from the generated `.xml` file. You wouldn't be able to make it a Roslyn Analyzer because it depends on the build completing first (for the `.xml` and `.dll` output, y'see) - but as a custom MSBuild post-build step it could work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom [DiagnosticSuppressor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnostics.diagnosticsuppressor?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.6.0) similar to this :

```cs
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
internal sealed class MyDiagnosticSuppressor : DiagnosticSuppressor
{
    private static readonly SuppressionDescriptor Rule = new SuppressionDescriptor("SUPCS1591", "CS1591", "Justification");

    public override ImmutableArray<SuppressionDescriptor> SupportedSuppressions => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

    public override void ReportSuppressions(SuppressionAnalysisContext context)
    {
        foreach (var diagnostic in context.ReportedDiagnostics)
        {
            if (!context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Location location = diagnostic.Location;
                SyntaxNode node = location.SourceTree.GetRoot(context.CancellationToken).FindNode(location.SourceSpan);
                if (!(node is InterfaceDeclarationSyntax || HasParentOfType<InterfaceDeclarationSyntax>(node)))
                {
                    context.ReportSuppression(Suppression.Create(Rule, diagnostic));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HasParentOfType<TSearched>(SyntaxNode syntaxNode) where TSearched : SyntaxNode
    {
        return syntaxNode != null && (syntaxNode.Parent is TSearched || HasParentOfType<TSearched>(syntaxNode.Parent));
    }
}
```

A few things that you could want to customize based on your question :

- The rule you're targetting, here we're targetting `CS1591` (the second constructor parameter for our `SuppressionDescriptor`)
- When to suppress the warning, here we're suppressing it whenever we're not on an interface declaration (`node is InterfaceDeclarationSyntax`) or within an  interface declaration (`HasParentOfType<InterfaceDeclarationSyntax>(node)`)

Note that the current code probably won't behave like you wish in a few edge cases like classes declared within an interface declaration but I think it's a pretty solid basis to start with.

Comment: Thanks for this. This solution works fine and I was able to easily suppress both `CS1591` and `SA1600` without much code changes.