# How to hide Visual Studio squiggly lines from analyzers suppressed by a DiagnosticSuppressor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis

#### Context

I have implemented a [`DiagnosticsSuppressor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.diagnostics.diagnosticsuppressor) that suppresses the [`CS1591`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1591) rule on all constructs except interfaces.

The suppressor works fine **when compiling code**:

- I see warnings in the build output for interfaces that lack xml documentation.
- I don't see warnings in the build output for things other than interfaces that lack xml documentation.

However, in the Visual Studio IDE, I see squiggly lines in class members that don't have xml doc, even though the suppressor should be suppressing that diagnostic (see screenshot).

[image: Visual Studio screenshot showing the squiggly lines]

#### Question

**What additional work needs to be done in order for the `DiagnosticSuppressor` to also remove the squiggly lines from the IDE?**

#### Code

This is the code of the `DiagnosticSuppressor`:

```cs
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public sealed class XmlDocumentationRequiredSuppressor : DiagnosticSuppressor
{
    public static readonly string[] SuppressedDiagnosticIds = { "CS1591", "SA1600" };

    public static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, SuppressionDescriptor> SuppressionDescriptorByDiagnosticId = SuppressedDiagnosticIds.ToDictionary(
        id => id,
        id => new SuppressionDescriptor("GOOSE001", id, "XML documentation is most important on interface members, but not on everything else."));

    public override ImmutableArray<SuppressionDescriptor> SupportedSuppressions { get; } = ImmutableArray.CreateRange(SuppressionDescriptorByDiagnosticId.Values);

    public override void ReportSuppressions(SuppressionAnalysisContext context)
    {
        foreach (var diagnostic in context.ReportedDiagnostics)
        {
            if (!context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Location location = diagnostic.Location;
                SyntaxNode? node = location.SourceTree?.GetRoot(context.CancellationToken).FindNode(location.SourceSpan);
                if (!(node is InterfaceDeclarationSyntax || HasParentOfType<InterfaceDeclarationSyntax>(node)))
                {
                    context.ReportSuppression(Suppression.Create(SuppressionDescriptorByDiagnosticId[diagnostic.Id], diagnostic));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool HasParentOfType<TSearched>(SyntaxNode? syntaxNode) where TSearched : SyntaxNode
    {
        return syntaxNode != null && (syntaxNode.Parent is TSearched || HasParentOfType<TSearched>(syntaxNode.Parent));
    }
}
```

#### More Details

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, version 17.6.4.

In the following screenshot, we see that the result from the build is correct, meaning that the reported warnings are only the ones that shouldn't be suppressed.
However, we see that this doesn't match what is reported in the Error List view, which contains warnings that should have been suppressed.

[image: Visual Studio screenshot showing the both the Error List and build output]

Edit: Related Rosylyn GitHub Discussion: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions/70598

Comment: Trying to comprehend why you would do that. I mean this is a specific product you're asking about and i'm not knocking the effort or the objective - but are You aware you can do this instead? 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp#suppress-violations-using-a-global-suppression-file

Comment: I want to suppress CS1591 only **partially** which is why I used a custom `DiagnosticSuppressor`. My goal is to enforce xml doc, but only on interfaces. I took this approach following the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77222836/c-sharp-analyzers-how-to-enforce-xml-doc-on-interface-members-and-not-everythi).

Comment: doubt a random c# developer stumbling across this question will have an answer, doesn’t seem like a broad use case - therefor I would suggest maybe ask there instead https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

Comment: or did you already? https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions/70573

Comment: @RandRandom Yes, I suppose I could ask this question on GitHub as well. (The discussion you linked is indeed about my project, but about another question that I had, which is now resolved). However, are you suggesting that this current question should be removed from SO?

Comment: No, you can keep the question as it by no means violates any rules. I just find it hard to believe that someone who isn’t directly involved in the development of this tooling will have an answer, because your requirement is so rare that I am confident to say 99.9% of all c# developer will have no idea about this topic, so I strongly believe if you want an answer the only options are to directly talk with a person involved in this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think analyzers run in separate processes. If you just created the analyzer (or DiagnosticSuppressor), you might have to restart Visual Studio (perhaps all instances) so all related processes are terminated. You can also restart your computer just to be safe.

Comment: That actually worked. (I didn't try closing all VS instances, I went straight ahead and restarted the PC.) Thanks!